# giving random array to dictionary in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Im having some problems with structuring my `for` loops. I want the numbers generated by `random.randint` to be different for each settings list in every dictionary.

```
PopulationSize = 2
AmountofSettings = 5
key_index = '_index'
key_par = 'Fitness'
key_set = 'Settings'
data_set = [0] * PopulationSize
dict_per = {}
settings_per = [0] * AmountofSettings
```

These give the variables and names of the keys in every dictionary

```
for i in range(len(data_set)):
```

in this for-loop I am going through every dictionary in the list.

```
    for x in range(len(settings_per)):
        settings_per[x] = random.randint(0, 9)
```

I believe my problem is in this part. currently it constructs a list  of 5 random integers, and assigns it to the `'Settings'` key in every dictionary. My goal is to have a new list in `'Settings'` in each dictionary.

```
        dict_per = {key_index: i, key_par: None, key_set: settings_per}
    data_set[i] = dict_per 
print(data_set)
```

The data structure coming out is correct. However, every `'Settings'` list in the main dictionary list contains the same integers. I want the lists to be all different.

For extra clarity. This is the output right now for the `data_list`. As you can see, the `'Settings'` are the same list of variables. I want the `'Settings'` lists to be different for every `dict`.

Output right now:

```
[{'_index': 0, 'Fitness': None, 'Settings': [1, 7, 5, 4, 8]}, {'_index': 1, 'Fitness': None, 'Settings': [1, 7, 5, 4, 8]}]
```

But the output that I want:

```
[{'_index': 0, 'Fitness': None, 'Settings': [1, 7, 5, 4, 8]}, {'_index': 1, 'Fitness': None, 'Settings': [4, 6, 8, 1, 3]}]
```

where the second `'Settings'` list is independent of the first.

Comment: How to solve what? You never actually posed a clear problem...

Comment: Im sorry. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Show, don't tell. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: I have added a picture of the output it gives with more clarity on the 'Settings' part. thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Please see the link and [ask]. Don't post pictures of code or text on this site.

Comment: Allright, I should have made it a little easier to understand with the indentations and the brackets. I have fixed that now.

Comment: Thanks for making the updates. Most new users I see just get frustrated and start arguing back. Given its current state, I'd say your question is good now. I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: For future reference, please don't break up your code like that. It makes it really hard to (a) copy, and (b) see what the indentation actually looks like

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you allocate `Settings_per` once, then set the same reference for each new `dict_per` that you make: `key_set: Settings_per`.

You might think that `dict_per` has the same issue, but it does not. Notice that in each iteration, you assign a new dictionary object to that name (`dict_per = {...}`), despite the fact that you initialize it to an empty dictionary in the beginning.

Start by removing the unnecessary allocations at the beginning: `dict_per` and `Settings_per`. Create `settings_per` properly in each iteration, as you do with `dict_per`, rather than just filling it in.

Next, notice that `dict_per` is being generated over and over, for each element of `settings_per`. There is no need to do that. You only need to generate it once.

It is conventional to use **snake_case** for most variable and fuction names in python. **CamelCase** is generally used with user-defined class names. Constants are conventionally written as **UPPERCASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES**.

Here is what the code looks like with these changes:

```
POPULATION_SIZE = 2
SETTINGS_COUNT = 5
KEY_INDEX = '_index'
KEY_PAR = 'Fitness'
KEY_SET = 'Settings'
data_set = [None] * POPULATION_SIZE

for i in range(POPULATION_SIZE):
    settings_per = [None] * SETTINGS_COUNT
    for x in range(SETTINGS_COUNT):
        settings_per[x] = random.randint(0, 9)
    dict_per = {KEY_INDEX: i, KEY_PAR: None, KEY_SET: settings_per}
    data_set[i] = dict_per
print(data_set)
```

The code above is already totally functional, but you can make it better. First satisfy yourself that you can rewrite the inner loop as follows:

```
settings_per = []
for x in range(SETTINGS_COUNT):
    settings_per.append(random.randint(0, 9))
```

That's the idiomatic expanded equivalent for a list comprehension:

```
settings_per = [random.randint(0, 9) for _ in range(SETTINGS_COUNT)]
```

`_` is often used to indicate a discarded loop variable.

Now you can write the entire outer loop as

```
data_set = [None] * POPULATION_SIZE
for i in range(POPULATION_SIZE):
    data_set[i] = {KEY_INDEX: i, KEY_PAR: None, KEY_SET: [random.randint(0, 9) for _ in range(SETTINGS_COUNT)]}
```

Now the outer loop is beginning to loop just like the form of the inner loop that we converted to a list comprehension:

```
data_set = [{KEY_INDEX: i, KEY_PAR: None, KEY_SET: [random.randint(0, 9) for _ in range(SETTINGS_COUNT)]} for i in range(POPULATION_SIZE)]
```